# Homology of the torus from the axioms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I'm supposed to show that for the Torus $T^d = (S^1)^d$ we have the formula:

$$ H_n(T^d) = \bigoplus_{i = 0}^d \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\binom{d}{i} H_{n-i}(\text{point}) = \begin{cases} R^\binom{d}{n}  &0\leq n \leq d \\ 0 & \text{else}   \end{cases}  $$

where $H$ is any ordinary homology theory. We have already proofed and its probably a consequence out of that the following things:

If $X$ is locally compact then $H_n(S^d \times X) = H_n (X) \times H_{n - d}(X)$
and we know the homology of the sphere i.e $H_n(S^d) = \begin{cases} R & d \neq 0,\ n = 0, d \\ 0 & d \neq 0,\ n \neq 0, d \\ R \oplus R & d = 0,\ n = 0 \\
0 & d = 0,\ n \neq 0 \end{cases} $

How can I prove the homology of the torus out of that?

Comment: Is this about generalized homology or about singular homology (and its relatives simplicial, cellular homology)? You write "where $H$ is any homology theory" but the last equality is only valid for singular homology, and so are the values of $H_n(S^d)$ you give.

Comment: In the lecture we said that H is a homology theory if it satisfies 5 axioms (see Bredon Topology): Homotopy, Excission, Existence of long exact sequence of a pair,  additivity and Dimensionaxiom. From this Axioms what I wrote should follow.

Comment: Right, because this already implies that $H$ is isomorphic to singular homology, although perhaps you haven't seen this yet :) Generally speaking "homology theory" now most often refers to theories which do not need to satisfy the dimension axiom, so I would recommend replacing "homology theory" by "ordinary homology theory" in your question; this will make it unambiguous what theories you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward proof by induction. For the base case $d = 1$ we directly see that $H_0(S_1) \cong H_1(S^1) \cong R = R^\binom{1}{0} = R^\binom{1}{1}$. Adopting the convention that $\binom{a}{b} = 0$ if $b < a$ or $b > a$ and assuming now that we've proven the identity up to some fixed $d - 1 \geq 1$, we have for all $n$ that
\begin{align}
    H_n(T^d) &= H_n(S^1 \times T^{d - 1}) \\
        &\cong H_n(T^{d - 1}) \oplus H_{n - 1}(T^{d - 1}) \\
        &\cong R^\binom{d - 1}{n} \oplus R^\binom{d - 1}{n - 1} \\
        &\cong R^\binom{d}{n}
\end{align}
where we use the binomial identity $\binom{d - 1}{n} + \binom{d - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{d}{n}$ for the last step.

Comment: thank you for your answer, are you doing induction over d,n simultansly?

Comment: @user1072285 Just over $d$. I've added some words to my answer to make this clearer.